# MYSQL query that contains 2 things I need in 1 query

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, sum, subquery

I have built a live scoring system for a game.  When the scores are entered into the MySQL database, they are entered like this...

```
ID    userid    sessionid    sprintid    pointvalue1    pointvalue2  pointvalue3
1      1          1             1             10            5             2
2      2          1             1             10            5             3
3      3          1             1             12            6             3
4      1          1             2             10            6             4
5      2          1             2             12            5             3
6      3          1             2              9            4             3
```

As you can see from the above, there is 1 session, 2 different sprints (iterations) and 3 different users.  I want to display a leader board.  The leader board would show (by iteration), user name (from another table), sprint, point value 1, point value 2, point value 3, sum of point value 1 cumulative for all iterations in that session.  So on iteration 1, point value 1 and sum of point value 1 cumulative would be the same.  But, in iteration 2, I should see a sum of point value 1 of 20 for user 1, 22 for user 2, and 21 for user 3, in the proper order (descending).  I tried a subquery using a select sum, but couldn't quite get it right, and I tried a SUM(IF()), which seemed like it would be right, but it's not.  I guess I need some guidance on which direction to go.

Comment: Possible to show the query that you have tried?

Comment: You seem to be using iteration and sprint interchangeably, makes it hard to understand. 
Is each 'iteration' a new query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this query will get you the raw data you want. You will probably want to adjust the query with some form of ordering on total points, and possibly `WHERE` and `LIMIT` clauses to meet your exact needs.

```
SELECT s1.userid, 
       s1.sessionid,
       s1.sprintid,
       s1.pointvalue1,
       s1.pointvalue2,
       s1.pointvalue3,
       SUM(s2.pointvalue1) AS sum_pointvalue1,
       SUM(s2.pointvalue2) AS sum_pointvalue2,
       SUM(s2.pointvalue3) AS sum_pointvalue3
FROM scores s1
JOIN (SELECT userid, 
             sessionid,
             sprintid,
             SUM(pointvalue1) AS pointvalue1,
             SUM(pointvalue2) AS pointvalue2,
             SUM(pointvalue3) AS pointvalue3
      FROM scores
      GROUP BY userid, sessionid, sprintid
     ) s2
ON s2.userid = s1.userid AND s2.sessionid = s1.sessionid AND s2.sprintid <= s1.sprintid
GROUP BY userid, sessionid, sprintid
ORDER BY sprintid
```

Output:

```
userid  sessionid   sprintid    pointvalue1     pointvalue2     pointvalue3     sum_pointvalue1     sum_pointvalue2     sum_pointvalue3
2       1           1           10              5               3               10                  5                   3
3       1           1           12              6               3               12                  6                   3
1       1           1           10              5               2               10                  5                   2
2       1           2           12              5               3               22                  10                  6
3       1           2           9               4               3               21                  10                  6
1       1           2           10              6               4               20                  11                  6
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db7870/5)